Material UI Autocomplete Categories in ReactJS
I'm using MUI Autocomplete and Formik and I wanted to group this into categories. If it has no sub_accounts, then it shouldn't have a header label. Something like this: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped
CODESANDBOX ------>
CLICK HERE
Expected outcome on the UI is something like:

Petty Cash

Cash In Bank - Bank of America

Bank of America - Single Proprietor
Bank of America - Corporate Entity


Cash

CIB - Bank of Vietnam

Bank of Vietnam Personal
Bank of Vietnam Checking Acc



Petty Cash, Cash In Bank - Bank of America, Cash and CIB - Bank of Vietnam should be aligned.
Cash In Bank - Bank of America and  CIB - Bank of Vietnam cannot be clicked/selected - only its sub_accounts can be selected as well as Petty Cash and Cash.
CODE
export const CashAccountAutocomplete = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors, setFieldValue, values },
  disabled,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (_, newValue, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clear") {
      setFieldValue(field.name, { id: "", name: "" });
      return;
    }
    setFieldValue(field.name, newValue);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (_, newInputValue) => {
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  };

  const extractSubAccounts = (accounts) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(accounts)) {
      console.error("Invalid accounts data. Expected an array.");
      return [];
    }

    return accounts.flatMap(
      ({ id, name, sub_accounts }) =>
        sub_accounts && sub_accounts.length > 0
          ? extractSubAccounts(sub_accounts) // Recursively extract sub-accounts
          : [{ id, name }] // Include the account if it has no sub-accounts
    );
  };

  const filteredData = extractSubAccounts(accounts);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...field}
      disabled={disabled}
      getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        typeof option === "string" ? option : option?.name || ""
      }
      renderOption={(props, option) => {
        return (
          <li {...props} key={option.id}>
            {option?.name}
          </li>
        );
      }}
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      options={filteredData || []}
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      filterSelectedOptions
      noOptionsText={"No data"}
      onChange={handleChange}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...props}
          error={touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] ? true : false}
          helperText={
            touched[field.name] &&
            errors[field.name] &&
            String(errors[field.name].id)
          }
        />
      )}
      fullWidth
    />
  );
};


Update the extractSubAccounts helper function to only set the isHeader property on elements are will be headers, and then also set an isSelectable property if there are no sub-array options.
const extractSubAccounts = (accounts) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(accounts)) {
    console.error("Invalid accounts data. Expected an array.");
    return [];
  }

  return accounts.flatMap(({ name, sub_accounts, ...account }) => [
    {
      ...account,
      name,
      isHeader: true,
      isSelectable: !sub_accounts?.length,
    },
    ...sub_accounts,
  ]);
};

Update the renderOptions callback to check both each list item's inHeader and isSelectable properties, the idea being that the list items that are headers and also options should be selectable and receive the "MuiAutocomplete-option" CSS classes and then also conditionally undo the padding that options have so the headers remain aligned.
renderOption={(props, option) => {
  return (
    <li
      key={option.id}
      {...(!option.isHeader || option.isSelectable ? props : {})}
      style={{
        paddingLeft:
          option.isHeader || option.isSelectable ? "1rem" : "2rem",
      }}
    >
      {option.isHeader && !option.isSelectable
        ? <strong>{option.name}</strong>
        : option.name}
    </li>
  );
}}



@Joseph Ah, oops, it was still selectable because the props with the handlers was unconditionally spread into all headers. Updated answer. If you want the headers to have a little bit of padding you can set that in the style prop or implement actual styled components to override & set the padding you'd like.

@Joseph How much padding do you want/need? Just the headers, or everything to be aligned the same?

@Joseph It looks like the default padding-left was about 1rem or 16px. You can further indent the options another 1rem. If you just wanted them all to line up then just use style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}.

I have implemented a solution here using hooks.
You need to sort the options property value of Autocomplete after filtering.

Where is the formik part?

I may have misunderstood your problem. From what I understand your problem was If it has no sub_accounts, then it shouldn't have a header label. I focused on that part. I am not familiar with formik.  Does the implementation solve your problem?

Not entirely. You have removed other things I needed in the CodeSandbox. It should be solved together with this. You can fork my codesandbox so its easier

Petty Cash, Cash In Bank - Bank of America, Cash and CIB - Bank of Vietnam should be aligned
